# Gridview item preview using .net 2.0

Tags: .net, javascript, ajax, .net-2.0

I have a GridView control that for each item has a Hyperlinkfield with a URL to an aspx page.

I want to (using AJAX libraries) to display the page preview in an inline window as the user hovers over each GridView row hyperlink.

Can anyone suggest the best way to implement a preview of each row's hyperlinked aspx page as the user hovers over each link on the row? Bearing in mind I'm using the .net 2.0 framework.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is a [JQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that you open (.dialog( 'open' )) on hyperlink hover and close (.dialog( 'close' )) when you leave the hyperlink.

You can manipulate the the hyperlink in the method onrowdatabound of your gridview.